# How do I create an attribute set based on default set in magento programmatically?

Tags: magento

I wrote the following code to create an attribute set programmatically in magento...

```
$skeletonID=Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup','core_setup')->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product','Default');
        // echo $skeletonID;
        $model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set');
        $entityTypeID = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
        $model->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeID);
        $model->setAttributeSetName("Mat");      
        $model->initFromSkeleton($skeletonID);
        $model->validate();
        $model->save();
```

Now I am able to see a new attribute set with same groups as the 'Default' Attribute set but, None of the attribute is assigned.The following is the screenshot of new Attribute set....

[image: Screenshot]

Please help me how to create the Attribute set based on Default.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a block in your modules config.xml that looks like so

```
<resources>
    <namespace_module_setup><!-- becomes folder under sql dir -->
        <setup>
            <module>Namespace_Module</module>
            <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
    </namespace_module_setup>
</resources>
```

This will allow you to place your installer code in the directory that is in your XML. You need to make sure that the version listed on the installer file matches the 1.2.0 of your module otherwise Magento will not be able to run your installer. To add an attribute Set, you can use the following data, I have never use it, but the entityTypeId defines whether it is a customer, shipping, category, product entity, each 1, 2, 3, 4 respectively.

```
/**
     * Add Attribute Set
     *
     * @param mixed $entityTypeId
     * @param string $name
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
     */
    public function addAttributeSet($entityTypeId, $name, $sortOrder = null)
    {
        $data = array(
            'entity_type_id'        => $this->getEntityTypeId($entityTypeId),
            'attribute_set_name'    => $name,
            'sort_order'            => $this->getAttributeSetSortOrder($entityTypeId, $sortOrder),
        );
    $setId = $this->getAttributeSet($entityTypeId, $name, 'attribute_set_id');
    if ($setId) {
        $this->updateAttributeSet($entityTypeId, $setId, $data);
    } else {
        $this->_conn->insert($this->getTable('eav/attribute_set'), $data);

        $this->addAttributeGroup($entityTypeId, $name, $this->_generalGroupName);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This is the code for adding an attribute to a set, just change the attribute set data

```
//app/code/local/Namespace/Module/sql/Namespace_Module_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php
    $installer = $this;
    /* @var $installer Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */

    $installer->startSetup();

        $data= array (
            'attribute_set' =>  'Default',
            'group' => 'General',
            'label'    => 'Some Label',
            'visible'     => true,
            'type'     => 'varchar', // multiselect uses comma-sep storage
            'input'    => 'text',
            'system'   => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => 1, //defaults to false; if true, define a group
        );

        $installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','attriute_code',$data)

        $installer->endSetup();
```

The above is a working example of an attribute-set and attributes installation for a module.

Comment: I dont want to do any thing in install script then what should I do